# Element at the bottom using AppBarLayout draws element behind Navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to have a navigation with fragments along different screens.
We have decided that the Toolbar has to go away when scrolling. That is  easy using AppBarLayout and layout_scrollFlags "scroll".

So I use a NestedScrollView that will contain the fragments.
Some fragments just contain a button that I want it to be placed at the bottom. Others are large menus that need to be scrollable.

So for this purpose I use the flag fillViewPort on the NestedScrollView. In case the fragment is short, it will fill the screen and the button will appear at the bottom.

The problem is that if I use the flag "scroll" on the AppBarLayout, if the fragment has a button on the bottom it is placed behind the navigation bar, while if I don't use the flag "scroll" NestedScrollView resizes to its proper size and the button is visible.

The test is very easy to reproduce in the preview of the layout on AndroidStudio.

Am I trying to do something weird? How can I achieve to have a button on the bottom for certain (small) fragments using the Coordinator and AppBarLayout with flags "scroll"?
Note that fitsSystemWindow does not make a difference for this.

This is just **without** using  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"`

[image]

This is using  `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"`

[image]

This is the code for the simplified layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

also just in case this is the "content_main.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** Adding a `<NestedScrollView>` alone by itself below the `AppBarLayout` will avoid the visibility of the screen as it takes the Width and Height of the screen, but `CoordinatorLayout` will shift the view one below the other by default.

Hence, the work-around would be to wrap the `<NestedScrollView>` in a separate layout like `<LinearLayout>` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this will work as expected, you will be able to see the view and also hide the toolbar on scroll.

Rest of the code remains the same. Try it, comment if any issues.

Comment: Yes! that made the trick. The only problem I see is that even with the button on the bottom the screen is still scrollable and toolbar goes away while scrolling, when actually there is nothing to scroll. But in any case, that is much better and much more usable. Thanks!